# Token is not allowed, because of invalid or empty chainId -EXACTONLINE

Tags: rest, exact-online

Currenlty setting up my first pipeline to ingest the data so I run alot of time the code which requests the new access tokens and refresh tokens. After so many request, I think I got block and cant request any new access token by using old refresh token as Im getting this error:

```
Token is not allowed, because of invalid or empty chainId
```

I saw this [article](https://forums.invantive.com/t/exact-online-error-token-is-not-allowed-because-of-invalid-or-empty-chainid-on-exact-online/2226) but was not helpful. How can I solve this problem without requesting the authorization code again?

Comment: I dont see the solution in the forum (am I missing something) and I also dont use invantive.

Comment: You mention "code which requests the __new__ access tokens and refresh tokens" as well as "using __old__ refresh token". Can you elaborate on that (preferably by editing the question, adding debugging details)? Using a refresh token that has been superseded by a newer refresh token (belonging to the same client ID and Exact Online user ID) might explain the error.

Comment: @RuudHelderman I think I was using an old refresh token and that why I was getting this error. Not sure anymore cause, I did not have this error after that day